# pandas groupby a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Imagine if you have a list of strings and a pandas dataframe with a column `Foo` that has words which may contain those strings:

`my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']`

df['Foo'] has words that contain 'A' or 'B' or 'C',

you can extract the ones that contain by `df.Foo.str.contains(my_list[0])` etc., but can you group by the rows that match the list? So the groupby would be by contains 'A' or 'B' or 'C'

Comment: Do you want words to appear in multiple groups?  For example abracadabra has all three, so should it appear in all three groups?  And if not, is there one letter that takes precedence over another?

Comment: Lets assume (to start) Foo only contains one of the three words

Comment: Does case matter?

Comment: no, lets say everything is lower case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by passing a function to groupby()

```
data = {'Foo': {0: 'apple',
  1: 'body',
  2: 'animal',
  3: 'cot',
  4: 'cord',
  5: 'bed',
  6: 'ant'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

      Foo
0   apple
1    body
2  animal
3     cot
4    cord
5     bed
6     ant
```

get_grp() will be called for each value in df['Foo']. Note: x is only the index of df so we have to pass some additional things

```
def get_grp(x, df, col_name, my_list):
    for c in my_list: 
        if c in df[col_name][x]:
            return c


 my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 g = df.groupby(lambda x : get_grp(x, df, 'Foo', my_list))
 print (type(g))
 print (g.count())

<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
   Foo
a    3
b    2
c    2
```

Note: get_grp() only returns one item of my_list.  So 'Ball' would only fall into one grouping and it would be 'a' because its the first item in my_list that we check